# Write a Custom Query in Custom Post type Listing

Tags: wordpress, custom-post-type, custom-wordpress-pages

I have created a Custom POST Type with Name "Members"

I want to show the List of submitted records which are submitted at Contact from 7 and Store with contact form advance Database.

is this possible .?
my question is I want to create a New Page in Admin in that I want to list out those submissions.

Comment: Can you elaborate the question? You need to store contact form 7 records in Members POST type?

Comment: I am already storing the contact form records using Contact Form Advanced Database. my question is I want to create a New Page in Admin in that I want to list out those submissions.

Comment: Ok so are you storing all the information inside "Members" CPT?

Comment: Yes, i want show them in List, Its already stored in CF7 Advanced Database

Comment: First you need to migrate the data from CF7 advanced database to "Members" CPT , you can do that via writing a plugin and use wp_insert_post to insert the data.

Comment: Thanks. Can you give some References.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you did not need to create a new page inside wp-admin if you have created a members CPT , that will automatically appear inside the wp-admin as a custom post type page.

Now you need to migrate the data as I said.

you need to use `global $wpdb` , [Link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb)

Use `$myrows = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT id, name FROM mytable" , ARRAY_A);` to get the data from contact form advance database table

Use `$wpdb->query("INSERT INTO wp_postmeta ( post_id, meta_key, meta_value) VALUES ('post_id','meta_key','meta_value')");` to insert the data inside wp_post and wp_postmeta tables (I used default prefix)

After this, records will auto appear inside the Members CPT page.

You need to write all the code inside contact form hook like the following ,

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'my_conversion' );
function my_conversion( $contact_form ) {

}
```